# Find Möbius Transformation over an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Find the Möbius transformation that applies the domain
$$\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{z}>0, |z-2|<1\}$$
onto an annulus
$$A(0;p,1)\text{ for some }p\in(0,1)$$

I don't even know where to start, I've been told I'm supposed to use
$$w=\frac{\zeta-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}\zeta},|\alpha|<1$$
first by defining a function $\zeta=f(z)$ to use the transformation but if I don't know how to start, could someone tell if it's true and give an insight on how to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you got the inequality on $|z-2|$ right? As written, it looks like the disk of radius $1$ about $z_0=2$.

Comment: @Lubin yes, it is $|z-2|<1$ i believe that transformation doesnt exist. am i wrong?

Comment: A mobius transformation does not turn a disk into an annulus. If you reverse the inequality, the first domain is then an annulus (on the Riemann sphere), so there is a mobius transformation that maps the first domain to the second.

Comment: And thus, @AndrewCollins , you are not wrong.

Comment: @Lubin, @runway44; thank you both very much.